# Select Statement Ignoring Where

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using:

```
SELECT SLN,
       PREFIX + ' ' + CAST(Number AS VARCHAR(16)) + ' Section: ' + CAST(ClassSection AS VARCHAR(16)) + ' ' + LOCATION + ' ' + ClassDay + ' Start: ' + StartTime + ' End: ' + EndTime AS Info
FROM Classes
WHERE Classes.IsActive=1
ORDER BY Number
```

Where Classes.IsActive is a bit and I'm wondering why when I execute the query it gives me rows that have IsActive = 0 along with the rows where IsActive = 1. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That doesn't sound possible.  My money is on you overlooking something.

Comment: What DB?  It seems impossible.  Please also select Classes.IsActive as a column in the result set.  unless there is a bug in your DB that you just uncovered, something else must be going on.

Comment: your not setting that query to anything, you should show all relevant code

Comment: Just to be sure, add `IsActive` as a column to your query and check. `Classes` - is it a view?

Comment: I just posted that because it's not even working in SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Who else is using the system at the same time?

Comment: How do you know whether the rows that are returned have IsActive=1 or IsActive=0?

Comment: @Austin . . . Add `IsActive` to the `select` list.  My hunch is that you have duplicates in the data with the flag set both ways.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was overlooking something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There had been extra classes added on to the table that I didn't know about. Thanks for the troubleshooting help